# How to "wait" for data from API

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I have a problem, 
How to wait for data from API?

I would write code like this:

```
List<User> userList = dataAPI.getAllUser();
```

I would have a list an use it wherever I want.
I don't want to Override any methods.

DataAPI:

```
public class DataAPI {
public DataAPI(){
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();

        userAPI = retrofit.create(UserService.class);
public class DataAPI {
    [...]
    private UsertService userAPI;

    public DataAPI(){
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();

        userAPI = retrofit.create(UserService.class);
   }

   Observable<List<User>> getAllUser() {
        return userAPI.getAllUser();
    }
}
```

UserService

```
    @GET("/user/all")
    Observable<List<User>> getAllUser();
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be done with rxJava, for more details: [read](https://medium.com/@kevalpatel2106/code-your-next-android-app-using-rxjava-d1db30ac9fcc)

Comment: I used rx java but it returns me type object Observer

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set timeout and increase it as you need to wait for the response coming from service. (Give priority to writeTimeout)

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
client .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
client .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
client .readTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("http://api.yourapp.com/")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .client(client)
    .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

@Kubek, what you need to do is subscribe to the observable.
What you should probably do is:

```
userAPI.getAllUser()
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.IO)
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.Main)
.subscribe(
// do some stuff 
)
```

For documentation on how to use subscribe method, refer: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribe.html